# Rails Select Box reject if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a nested form which has select box to assign songs.

My models are songs have many setlists and vice versa, through an allocations model. Setlists accept nested attributes for allocations.

My form is as follows:

```
<div>
  <%=nested_form_for @allocation do|builder|%>
    <%=builder.label :song_id, "Pick a song" %>

     <%= builder.hidden_field :setlist_id, value: @setlist.id %>

     <%= builder.select(:song_id, options_for_select(@selections), 
     {include_blank: true}, html:{multiple: true, size: 7}) %>

    <%=builder.submit "Add Song", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I want to have it so that it rejects the allocation from being created if the blank prompt is selected. I've tried:

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:song_id].blank? }
```

but that doesn't allow the form to submit as the nested attribute is invalid. I thought the point of the reject_if was that it would silently ignore this?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? `a[:song_id] == 0`

Comment: And are you sure it's coming as `0`? According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) the value of the blank option should be empty/`nil`.

Comment: When I searched for the record to see how it was possibly saved it came back with an allocation with a song id of zero,and a[:song_id]==0 doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Ok so the reason it was setting as zero was because in my controller I was converting the song id to an integer using a to_i method. Unnecessary and it nil converted to an integer is zero. I've changed that so now the form is rendering ok but won't let the user submit the data if the song field is left blank.